# Compile Error: Use constexpr to declare std::array size

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, constexpr, stdarray

I am learning `constexpr` and, for my understanding, `constexpr` tells the compiler to calculate functions during compile time instead of running time. I used the following code for testing but bumped into an error I really don't understand. Can you please explain why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

constexpr int foo(int i)
{
    return i + 5;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    std::array<int, foo(5)> arr; // OK
    // But...
    std::array<int, foo(i)> arr1; // Error
}
```

The error is:  the value of '`i`' is not usable in a constant expression. Why? `i` is declared beforehand why does it have to be a `const`?

Answer (score 6):

> for my understanding constexpr tells the compiler to calculate functions during compile time instead of running time.

Not exactly: with `constexpr` the compiler can (not must) calculate function compile time. And the compiler do it when it's necessary and possible.

In case of

```
std::array<int, foo(5)> arr; // OK
```

it's necessary (because the second template argument of `std::array` must be known at compile time) and possible (because 5 is known at compile time).

But with

```
int i = 10;
std::array<int, foo(i)> arr1; // Error
```

it's necessary (`std::array`) but not possible (because `i` is a not-constant variable and the compiler can't use the `i` value compile time but only run time).

It's necessary but not possible, so the error.

But you can write

```
int i { 10 };
int j { foo(i) };
```

because it's not possible call `foo(i)` compile time but it isn't necessary (because `j` can be initialized run time). So `foo(i)` is called (supposedly) run time.

To compile the `std::array` using `foo(i)`, you should define `i` as `constexpr` (or `const`)

```
constexpr int i { 10 };
```

so the compiler can use the value of `i` compile time.

> Why? i is declared beforehand why does it have to be a const?

Short answer: because the C++11 standard say so.

Long answer: because, in this way, it's simpler to construct a compiler. If you want to use a value compile time, you can declare it as `constexpr` and the compiler check that it is never modified. It's (relatively) simple to do.

Otherwise, if you could use compile time the value of a not-constant variable, the compiler should follow the story of a variable to determine it's value when used in a `constexpr` function. In your toy example is simple, in real life would be a nightmare.